# Cant hover the second like

Tags: html, css, hover, mousehover, onhover

```css
nav {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    bordnaver-right: none;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-pack: center
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
    -moz-box-lines: multiple;
    -o-box-lines: multiple;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -o-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}
nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    //border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    //border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #feaa38;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F5F5F5), to(#feaa38));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #feaa38);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #feaa38);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F5F5F5, #feaa38);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F5F5F5, #feaa38);
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -o-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #feaa38;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #FFF;
}
nav ul li ul {
    display: flex;
}
nav ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:-999em;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
    -moz-box-lines: multiple;
    -o-box-lines: multiple;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -o-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width:100%;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    top: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
}
nav ul li ul li {
    background: #b56906;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000 !important;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
nav ul li ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    -moz-flex-flow: column wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width:100%;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover > ul {
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
nav ul li:Last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>first
            <ul>
                <li>1st
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>2nd
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>3rd
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>4th
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>5th
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>second
            <ul>
                <li>1st
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>2nd
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>3rd
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>4th
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>5th
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>third
            <ul>
                <li>1st
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>2nd
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>3rd
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>4th
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>5th
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>fourth
            <ul>
                <li>1st
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>2nd
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>3rd
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>4th
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>5th
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>fifth
            <ul>
                <li>1st
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>2nd
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>3rd
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>4th
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>5th
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have this nav bar.

What I want is to get the hover state of `UL LI UL LI` but I cant hover it.

How did I know it?Because when I add

```
nav ul li ul li:hover a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

The text color of 1st should be white. But it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got :hover pseudoclass in the wrong place.

```
nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
```